# Java regular expression to match {{characters inside double curly brace}}

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match everything inside double curly brackets in a string. I am using the following expression:

```
\{\{.*\}\}
```

Some examples:

`The {{dog}} is not a cat.` This correctly matches {{dog}}

However,
`The {{dog}} is a {{cat}}` matches everything after the first match instead of returning two matches. I want it to match twice, once for {{dog}} and once for {{cat}}

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Regex uses a greedy algorithm (and thus wants to grab as big a string as will match). Does that help or do you need more?

Comment: This should do the work \{\{.*?\}\}

Comment: If you recieved you answer accept the one that has helped you the most

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The greedy `.*` matches anything (except line breaks), so when there are more than one `}}` in the string, it always matches the last `}}` (if there aren't any `\r` and `\n` between the two `}}`!).

Try to make the `.*` match reluctant (ungreedy) like this:

```
\{\{.*?}}
```

That's correct, you needn't escape the `}`.

You could also do:

```
\{\{[^}]*}}
```

if a `{{ ... }}` cannot contain a single `}` itself.

Answer (score 5):

Try with `\{\{.*?\}\}`

I believe it's because the pattern you have is greedy.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification) explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use non-greedy match:

```
\{\{.*?\}\}
```

to match everything between braces, use:

```
\{\{(.*?)\}\}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the "non-greedy" modifier - so your regex is `\{\{.+?\}\}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{(.*?)\\}\\}");
Matcher matchPattern = pattern.matcher("The {{cat}} loves the {{dog}}");
while(matchPattern.find()) {
    System.out.println(matchPattern.group(1));
}
```